# Compressing an MongoDB object ID in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm looking for a way to encode an object's ID into a smaller string and also a way to decode it again.

Basically I want for instance an ID "47cc67093475061e3d95369d" to turn into something like "adff232"… a'la bit.ly, etc.

Is there any gem to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use base62 encoding. There are several gems, but it should be as simple as:

```
id.to_s.to_i(16).base62_encode
```

In your example case, your output would be `sTIRzdDETzTR6YOh`.

Comment: Thanks! What about the other way round? From sTIRzdDETzTR6YOh to 47cc67093475061e3d95369d?

Comment: You have to be careful of base 62 since search engines are not case sensitive.

Comment: I used another way to solve this by adding a new unique field that can be used for URLs: rand(Time.now.to_i).to_s(36)

Comment: @khell What's this have to do with search engines, though? MongoDB is case-sensitive. Regarding the rand solution, be careful. You could end up with an ID collision that way.

Comment: @Erik, you'll just use `base62_decode(compressed_id).to_s(16)` to get the equivalent Mongo ID hex string.

Comment: That's a guess, why would he need a short id :). Yea with unique index things should be OK.

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone! I think I'll go with the base62 approach…

Answer (score 0):

If you don't intend to display the compressed string, you can compress the `id` by half with `pack` and `unpack`:

```
id = "47cc67093475061e3d95369d"
puts id.length             #=> 24

compressed_id = id.to_a.pack('H*')
p compressed_id            #=> "G\314g\t4u\006\036=\2256\235"
puts compressed_id.length  #=> 12

uncompressed_id = compressed_id.unpack('H*')[0]
p uncompressed_id          #=> "47cc67093475061e3d95369d"
puts uncompressed_id == id #=> true
```